# Given a Percentage, Find the Smallest Integer Dividend for an Unknown Number of Integer Tests

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, percentages

In a classroom exam where each question is worth 1 point and the number of exam questions are unknown.  If the student receives results of a test in a percentage with decimals, let's say `78.5%`, what is the formula to determine the smallest integer dividend that is the number of questions on the test?

### For example:

- 78.5% = 785/1000
- 78.5% = 471/600
- 78.5% = 157/200

Through successive approximation, 200 appears to be the number of questions on the test, because 157 out of 200 yields the given percentage.

Comment: In your example, the minimum number of questions is $\frac{1000}{\gcd(1000,785)}$. By the way, above the example, you are asking for the number of questions, while below the example, you are calculating the number of correct answers. It is not clear which one of them it is that you want, so I suggest that you make up first, and then fix your question accordingly.

Comment: Barak, yes that formula works.  Could you post it as an answer please?
=785/GCD(1000,785)

Comment: Fix the question first. It is not clear if you want the minimum number of questions or the minimum number of correct answers. And $157$ is **NOT** the number of questions on the test!

Comment: OK, corrected.  Thanks in advance for your answer.

Comment: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given an input of $x$ percentage, where $x$ can be represented on base $10$ as $m$ digits before the decimal point and $n$ digits after the decimal point, the minimum number of questions is:

$$\frac{10^{m+n}}{\gcd(10^{m+n},10^nx)}$$

Comment: Excellent!  I converted your answer into Excel, where cells are mapped to variables for m, n and x:  `=POWER(10,m+n)/GCD(POWER(10,m+n), POWER(10,n)*x)`

Comment: @MAbraham1: No problem :)